# Валидация каждого элемента из списка инпутов AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Упрощенный код:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">

    <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-pattern="/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ\-\s]{1,}$/" id="lastnameid{{key}}">

    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="FormName.lastName.$dirty && FormName.lastName.$invalid">
        Некорректная фамилия
    </div>

</div>
```

Убрал лишние элементы. Замечу, что items - это модель angularJS, представляет собой массив объектов.

Такая конструкция валидирует только в случае неправильного значения в последнем инпуте, но сообщение показывает около всех. Мне необходим изменяемый список инпутов на клиенте (удаление и добавление реализовано), но валидация должна быть у каждого отдельно.

Пробовал делать массив инпутов `lastName[{{key}}]`, и обращаться `FormName.lastName[key]` - не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть блок в `<ng-form>` и обращаться при валидации через `name` добавленного `ng-form`, в итоге у вас получится такой код:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">
  <ng-form name="formItem">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-pattern="/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ\-\s]{1,}$/" id="lastnameid{{key}}">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="formItem.lastName.$dirty && formItem.lastName.$invalid">
        Некорректная фамилия
    </div>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

Судя по описанию в [документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) добавление `ng-form` должно помочь решить вашу проблему

Comment: Спасибо, я не сразу понял суть ответа, т.к. форму я использую, просто нужно форму внести внутрь цикла `items`.